# Flex content overflows container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why does the contents of my flexbox overflow it's parents? In my example -
 https://jsfiddle.net/zbvrL401/ please resize the browser vertically. The contents of the list go off and above the page.

I'm expecting for the contents not to out of bounds over the top of the page.

How can I prevent this?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul>
     <li>list item one</li>
     <li>list item two</li>
     <li>list item three</li>
     <li>list item four</li>
     <li>list item five</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background: gold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

ul{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

Comment: Try `ul {margin: 0}`

Comment: Nenad Vracar - then the items are not spaced evenly anymore.

Comment: Try adding {height: 100%, overflow: auto} in your parent absolute container div.

Comment: Abhishek Jain - does not work.

Comment: Nenad Vracar - absolute madness, how would they be evenly spaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated (thanks to [DHolbert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542201/flex-content-overflows-container/46542453?noredirect=1#comment80063626_46542453))

If the items size is bigger than the container, `space-around` behaves like `center`, where it overflow equally at top/bottom.

Src: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-justify-content-space-around

---

One solution is to make the `container` a flex container, set it its `align-items` to `flex-start` and change from `height` to `min-height` on the `ul`.

Additionally, setting `overflow: auto` on `continer` will make it scroll properly, and since `ul` became a flex row item, it needs a width.

```css
.container {
    background: gold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;                /*  added  */
    align-items: flex-start;      /*  added  */
    overflow: auto;               /*  added  */
}
ul{
    width: 100%;                  /*  added  */
    min-height: 100%;             /*  changed  */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;    
    margin: 0;                    /*  added  */
}

li {
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <ul>
     <li>list item one</li>
     <li>list item two</li>
     <li>list item three</li>
     <li>list item four</li>
     <li>list item five</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work, items now just bunch up over each other.

Comment: @panthro Yes, as the ul has a fixed height of 100%. What should happen when they do't fit?

Comment: They should overflow at the bottom. Not at the top.

Comment: @panthro Updated my answer

Comment: Superb. Thanks very much.

Comment: RE "It appears Flexbox column has some issues here, in combination with space-around" -- Really, it's just that `space-around` behaves like `center` (i.e. it makes things overflow equally off start/end) if the container is smaller than its items.  Quoting the spec: "If the leftover free-space is negative ... this value is identical to 'center'." https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-justify-content-space-around

Comment: @dholbert Thanks for that, never cross my mind it was by design :) ... updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because the parent div is positioned absolute therefore it only takes up as much space as visible before scrolling. The height of the ul list simply exceeds that height of the parent.

If you remove the position absolute it doesn't overflow the golden background color.

Comment: Unfortunatly I need an absolute parent div.

Answer (score -1):

```
.container {
    background: gold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display:inline-table;
}
```

Comment: Flex solution please - I want to know why this is happening with flexbox.

Comment: just add the display:inline-table in the container class, it will fix the li from the top of the page and also cover the background color in various screen resolution.